# What is a more inclusive version of "pedestrian"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, terminology, political-correctness

A pedestrian [noun] is a "person going on foot" (Merriam Webster).

Is there a more inclusive term that also includes people in wheelchairs and other mobility devices, but excluding people in vehicles like cars. Preferably more specific than just "people".

Most of the synonyms I looked up were more specific than pedestrian (as much fun as "perambulator" is). "Mover" is closer, but mostly seems to refer to the occupation.

Sample sentence: This street is meant only for pedestrians, so please do not drive down it.

Comment: Searching for that phrase leads me to a Canadian legal definition of pedestrian as [a person afoot, or an invalid or child in a wheelchair or carriage](https://www.bclaws.gov.bc.ca/civix/document/id/complete/statreg/96318_05) which works to an extent. I haven't found a dictionary definition that is that inclusive, and it seems to be mainly a legal distinction.

Comment: Agree with @DLu, in traffic law, the term "pedestrian" can cover all sorts of things from people in wheelchairs or motorized scooters, to people on skateboards or skis. It's extremely common to classify a wheelchair user as a pedestrian. A sign reading "pedestrians only" is hardly intended to exclude wheelchair users.

Comment: You do not appear to have much experience in the psychology of injunctions, judging by your sample sentence. In reality, you are looking for an alternative to a sign that says "Pedestrians only!". And I suspect that the average man in the street is not a Latin scholar.

Comment: I doubt you'd find a word that also covered sedan chairs. Seriously, I think you're stuck with an inclusive (or exclusive) list.

Comment: Not quite the same thing but "Walking and Wheeling" is often used for moving on foot and by wheelchair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I regard as nonsense the idea that a more “inclusive” expression is needed, but *alternative* expressions are not difficult to find. One more clunky alternative to *pedestrian* is:

> non-vehicular traffic

But why use three words when one will do?

A real-world alternative to your sentence is more acceptable and would be:

> Vehicles prohibited!

There is a principle here: if you can’t find a suitable definition for what something **is**, try defining it by what it **is not**.

Comment: Whether that will work for the OP's purposes depends on how one understands the concepts of a vehicle. Most people would probably understand it so that it excludes wheelchairs, but somebody could pedantically argue that wheelchairs are vehicles. This is mirror image of most people understanding the concept of a pedestrian to include those who move about in wheelchairs, but some people pedantically arguing that it doesn't.

Comment: @jsw29 — Some of us understand how language works, others expect English to consist of words with an intrinsic legal definition of some concept.  Meanwhile Rome burns.

Comment: In the US, at least, no new term is needed because the disabled who require a wheelchair or OPDMD have a specific right to access and use pedestrian areas. You have to specifically argue to prevent this, and it is rarely successful. (An example is that you don't have to plow and shovel 20 feet of snow in the Colorado Mountains to provide winter access to year-round public recreation sites).

Comment: @PhilSweet — Of course, most English-speaking countries have similar laws or behaviour. As, I said, the whole thing is nonsense. However I don’t think this site should concern itself with the laws of any particular regions, and my answer restricted itself to English language and usage.

Answer (score 1):

'Wheelchair users' covers persons being pushed by another person, persons propelling a manual device and persons steering an electric device.

So I suggest that 'wheelchair users' are a specific *category* of persons.

Another category is 'pedestrians' which covers persons walking, persons carrying another person (usually a child) and persons walking with an aid of some kind (Zimmer frame or crutches).

All of these could be described as 'pavement users'.

So :

> This street is meant only for pavement users, so please do not drive down it.

The 'street' is thus  being defined as not possessing a carriageway, but only containing a pavement.

I am using BrE and assuming that 'sidewalk' would replace 'pavement' where appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

This is interesting. Typically, the people included in this way were described as having feet to walk with (pedestrians), but wheelchairs have been around for a long time. If I were wheelchair bound, I think I would be a little insulted by this, so it must be a problem. The closest I can come to an answer is [people] [citizenry] [population] [attendees] etc **moving about** the [city] [gardens] [museum] etc

As far as the law is concerned, wheelchair bound would be included in 'pedestrians' (pedestrians at crosswalks etc) //Also, in everyday parlance, if someone were to refer to 'pedestrian traffic' I think most would not even consider that wheelchair bound should not be included.

Comment: If you were wheelchair-bound I think you would be more concerned with actual access than the Latin derivation of street signs.

Comment: You are correct sir, which means my feeling of non-inclusiveness becomes an insult to injury.